# Use reference of UICollectionView inside NSOperation

Tags: swift

I want to use reference of a `UICollectionView` inside my `NSOperation` but I cannot figure out how to create it or pass it as an argument.

I was thinking of creating a var and then init inside `NSOperation` like:

```
class MyOperation: Operation {

    var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    init(col: UIColletionView) {
        collectionView = col
    }
}
```

And then using it as an argument when passing operation to queue:

```
myQueue.addOperation(MyOperation(col: collectionView))
```

But I get an error on the `init` line: "use of undeclared type". I know it's undeclared, I won't know what it is until I get the argument.

Comment: Maybe a typo in the initializer: col is of type `UIColletionView`; did you mean `UICollecionView` (with a "c")?

Comment: well thats not embarrassing at all.  Im going to stop looking at this for a while.  Thanks

Comment: lol @AndreasOetjen one typo exchanged for another...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

addOperation has a [block parameter overload](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/operationqueue/1412949-addoperation) as well.  You can capture the collectionView in the operation block, but really you shouldn't.  UI updates should only happen on the main thread, so really you should just capture the model, do some work in the background and then dispatch on the main thread back to some function or block that will update the collectionView.  This example assumes its not going to outlive the ViewController, which is often not a good assumption to make.  Use [weak self] and bail out if self is gone if you are not going to cancel the operation when the viewController disappears.

```
myQueue.addOperation {
     //Update model here
     DispatchQue.main.asynch {
         self.collectionView.reloadData()
     }
}
```

Comment: Stupid question number 2 then:  couldn't i just check that the view is viewController is visible before doing any update? :  if (ViewController().isViewLoaded && (ViewController().view.window != nil)) { then go main queue?

Comment: That captures self which causes the lifetime of self to be extended until the closure completes.  [weak self] doesn't extend the life of self.  if you don't care if the viewController is around while its off screen then window!= nil will work.  You can test your life time by adding in a print to deinit on the VC and add a NSthread. sleepForTimeInterval in your block to artificially make it outlast your view controller.

Comment: i don't know what that means but it sounds legit.  I shall go read more.